`.permit! ` is not defined in rails test envornment
(byebug) params.require(:user_documents).permit!
#<ActionController::Parameters {"0"=>#<ActionController::Parameters {"document_type_id"=>"12", "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f2c532602b0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20240917-9912-oqmfr8.pdf>, @original_filename="Tate sir.pdf", @content_type="application/pdf", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user_documents[0][file]\"; filename=\"Tate sir.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n">} permitted: true>, "1"=>#<ActionController::Parameters {"document_type_id"=>"13", "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f2c532600f8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20240917-9912-hnt968.pdf>, @original_filename="Tate sir.pdf", @content_type="application/pdf", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user_documents[1][file]\"; filename=\"Tate sir.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n">} permitted: true>} permitted: true>

above in the rails development server but same code getting error in the test as below
params.require(:user_documents).permit!
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `permit!' for [#<ActionController::Parameters {"file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fe16dd2f630 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20240917-11539-91yhjb.pdf>, @original_filename="sample.pdf", @content_type="application/pdf", @headers="content-disposition: form-data; name=\"user_documents[][file]\"; filename=\"sample.pdf\"\r\ncontent-type: application/pdf\r\ncontent-length: 3006720\r\n">, "document_type_id"=>"83"} permitted: false>, #<ActionController::Parameters {"file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fe16dd38b68 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20240917-11539-pv7tqg.pdf>, @original_filename="sample1.pdf", @content_type="application/pdf", @headers="content-disposition: form-data; name=\"user_documents[][file]\"; filename=\"sample1.pdf\"\r\ncontent-type: application/pdf\r\ncontent-length: 62102\r\n">, "document_type_id"=>"84"} permitted: false>]:Array
Did you mean?  permutation

nil

below is the controller method code
 def create
        @user_documents = []
        errors = []

        # Ensure that user_documents_params returns a hash of document entries
        byebug
        user_documents_params = params.require(:user_documents).permit!

        ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
          user_documents_params.each do |_index, doc_params|
            existing_document = @current_user.user_documents.find_by(document_type_id: doc_params[:document_type_id])

            if existing_document
              if existing_document.update(doc_params)
                @user_documents << existing_document
              else
                errors.concat(existing_document.errors.full_messages)
              end
            else
              new_user = @current_user.user_documents.new(doc_params)
              if new_user.save
                @user_documents << new_user
              else
                errors.concat(new_user.errors.full_messages)
              end
            end
          end

          if errors.empty?
            render json: { success: true, message: "Files are uploaded successfully" }
          else
            render json: { errors: errors }, status: :unprocessable_entity
          end
        end
      end

      private

      def user_document_params
        params.require(:user_documents)
      end
      

does anyone have any idea why code behaving different in different environment
used byebug to check if the issue still persist
As you ask please check

require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe Api::V1::UserDocumentsController, type: :request do
  let!(:user) { create(:user) }
  let!(:file1) { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(Rails.root.join("spec/fixtures/sample.pdf"), "application/pdf") }
  let!(:file2) { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(Rails.root.join("spec/fixtures/sample1.pdf"), "application/pdf") }
  let!(:document_type1) { create(:document_type, name: "Type1") }
  let!(:document_type2) { create(:document_type, name: "Type2") }

  let(:params) do
    {
      user_documents: [
        { document_type_id: document_type1.id.to_s, file: file1 },
        { document_type_id: document_type2.id.to_s, file: file2 },
      ],
    }
  end

  describe "GET api/v1/user_documents" do
    before do
      3.times { create(:user_document, user: user) }
    end
    context "when user is login in " do
      before do
        get "/api/v1/user_documents", headers: authorized_headers(user)
      end
      it "return user documents", :show_in_doc, doc_title: "Get all the documents" do
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
      end
    end
  end

  describe "POST /api/v1/user_documents" do
    # In your spec file (e.g., spec/requests/api/v1/user_documents_controller_spec.rb)

    context "when user is logged in" do
      before do
        post "/api/v1/user_documents", params: params, headers: authorized_headers(user, content_type: "multipart/form-data")
      end

      it "returns successful response for bulk upload", :show_in_doc, doc_title: "Upload multiple documents" do
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
        json_response = JSON.parse(response.body)
        expect(json_response["success"]).to be(true)
        expect(json_response["message"]).to eq("Files are uploaded successfully")
      end

    end
  end
end

above is my rspec test case simple to check

You don't actually want permit! here as you're just needlessly causing a mass assignment vulnerability. You could just use params.require(:user_documents); user_documents_params = params.permit(user_documents: [:document_type_id, :file]).

It's not ENV issue, it's most probably an issue in your tests where you send params in a wrong way. Pay attention to the error message: permit! is not define on an array which only element is ActionController::Parameters object. Please share your tests to confirm that.

I second @Greg's comment. generally "Array" params would be submitted to the backend as a Hash of {array_position => value} as you can see in your byebug. You are most likely submitting them directly to the controller action as an Array. This can easily be solved with {user_documents: your_current_array.each_with_index.to_h} but until we see the actual test we cannot provide a specific answer. Just a diagnosis of the current one.
